# Extract dates from facebook - date of established friendship / date of when person joined fan page / group

Tags: facebook, api, date, facebook-page

is there a way (API) to extract the date of a established friendship or the date of when a specific person joined a fan page/group in Facebook?

I haven't found anything in the docs and the Web, but as you can see in Facebook when you established your friendship with a given friend I still hoping there is a way for extracting it.

Thanks and cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

For friends and groups, Facebook does directly expose that data via the API. You can take a look at the FQL documentation. This has the most detailed information about what is exposed via the API. The `friend` and `group_member` don't have any record of when the relationship was created.

You can get some information by querying the user's `stream` to find the friendship/membership announcement:

```
fql?q=SELECT post_id, type, message, description, created_time, attribution FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND strpos (description, 'are now friends') > 0
```

However you'll need to concatenate several of these queries to get all information, as each `stream` query is limited to a maximum of 30 days worth of data or 50 posts.

Pages are easier. You can tell when a user liked a page via the `created_time` column in the `page_fan` table.